# NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xml/serialize/OutputFormat

Tags: java, xml, apache

My application cannot find OutputFormat even though I have included the xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar in my .M2 folder.

I am able to view the class file.

Does anyone have any ideas why this would be? Am I using an incorrect version?

Comment: check `classpath`, it might have multiple `xercesImpl` jars..

Comment: @harsh I checked and there is only one version of that jar.

Comment: are you using maven? If so, do an `eclipse:clean` and `eclipse:eclipse` again.

Comment: Yes, using Maven. I've cleaned and rebuilt the project to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Tomcat config in my Intellij was not set up correctly. The exploded war file did not have the xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar. I added it to my 'endorsed' folder in Tomcat and it now works.